# Get specific token TRADING HISTORY BSC

Tags: solidity, javascript, bsc

We are trying to make token trading dex history but so far we havent found anything to make it, yes we have found different apis that that we planned to buy but trading history was slow af. Is there any way to connect to PanckakeSwap to solidity and get token history data

something like that

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When a token is swapped on pancakeswap, a Swap() event is emitted. (https://bscscan.com/address/0x531febfeb9a61d948c384acfbe6dcc51057aea7e#code#L483). If you know which pair you want to build an history for, just query an archive node for all the swap events for that specific pair and build your history from there

Comment: Do you maybe know what would I need to query on the node to get that info?

Comment: @Luc you would ask for events (logs). You have to have access to a node that is willing to give you the information you want. Binance's public nodes recently disabled the ability to ask for events (logs)